# Reservation for Campgrounds in the Everglades in May

Tags: bookings, camping, everglades

We plan to stay in the everglades with our own tent for multiple nights. Is there a reservation needed?

Comment: There are multiple campgrounds in the Everglades. They might have different policies and different crowds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reservations are generally recommended during the high season November-April.
I was there in January and all the campings were packed.

If you can plan in advance I'd say a reservation is better.

Flamingo
http://www.nps.gov/ever/planyourvisit/flamcamp.htm